# How to create dynamic CSS based on user input

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

A user should be able to design a room (room is a model) in my Rails app. When the user visits `myapp.com/room/1` the room with its content and specific design is shown.

The design or CSS of the room is based on room parameters (color1, color2, ...) and some random generated design characteristics (font type, image border, ...). These characteristics are stored in the room model when the room is saved.

I don't see how I can generate a specific CSS for each room. When the user visits `myapp.com/room/1` my app should build specific CSS (or SCSS) for room1. Where (what controller) should I build that CSS?

Thanks

Comment: how is store design definition? What kind of information is defined?

Comment: This is a clear question to those who have programmed in Rails.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make your `RoomsController` respond to the CSS format as well in order to get this to work:

```
# app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb
class RoomsController
  def show
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.css
    end
  end
end
```

Then you need to implement a template to be rendered for the CSS format:

```
/* app/views/rooms/show.css.erb */
.room {
  background-color: <%= @room.color1 %>;
  color: <%= @room.color2 %>;
}
```

Note how this is very similar to a regular template. You need to make sure that this results in valid CSS.

You need to make sure the stylesheet is included when the user visits the page. Let's say a user can browse their room design when they visit `/rooms/1`. This will render a HTML template, which we could define as follows:

```
<!-- app/views/rooms/show.html.erb -->
<% content_for :stylesheet_includes do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag(room_path(@room, format: :css)) %>
<% end %>

<div class="room">
  Room Contents Here
</div>
```

Notice that I've used `content_for` around the stylesheet link tag. We can use this to make sure the stylesheet link tag is rendered nicely in the head of the layout:

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<head>
  <%= yield :stylesheet_includes %>
</head>
```

Of course you'll need to fill in the details yourself, but this would be the most logical approach for the problem.

Comment: my css rule is quite coplex(render chart). I have to write to scss. Is there a way to render to template like 'app/views/rooms/show.css.scss.erb' and then compile scss to css?

Answer (score -1):

If you design your controller to respond to the show action with json requests, you'll be able to retrieve the attributes of the Room object in json format

`http://localhost.com:3000/rooms/1.json`

`{"id":1,"color1":"black","color2":"green","created_at":"2014-12-15T19:52:21.235Z","updated_at":"2014-12-15T19:52:21.235Z"}`

In that case, you can use javascript to make the [get request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), retrieve the data in JSON, and subsequently use that data to manipulate the dom.

`$.get( "rooms/1.json", function( data ) {
   alert(data);
});`